# How can I perform checks and screen scrolls more efficiently in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

I am bulding a web app that has a large form.  The top part of the form has FIVE buttons where a user clicks one and it opens a dialog box.  The buttons are for Sex, Weight, Height, Hair color and Eye color.

The buttons start out showing the name of the category and a question mark, like this:

```
Sex - ?
Weight - ?
Height - ?
Hair - ?
Eyes - ?
```

So, for example, if someone clicks the Weight button, a JS dialog pop-up that allows them to choose their weight. Once they do and close the dialog, the question mark changes to show the actual weight they picked and then they can click another button.

The rest of the form has "normal" fields (standard input fields) and I am using Jquery validate to validate them.  That all works fine, but Jquery validate won't work well for the buttons setup I described above, so I validate them myself using the code below.

Essentially, I check to see if there is a question mark in any of them and if so (that means the user didn't choose it yet), it "shows" a span that has a "required" message in it AND it scrolls to the top of the page because otherwise it only scrolls to the first invalid Jquery Validate form (which is always lower on the page).

I'm fairly certain this code below is VERY inefficient.  Do you agree?  It seems flat-out wrong that if Sex still has a question mark, the code is telling the screen to scroll to the top, but still has to go through 4 more checks.

```
      if ( $sexdisplaytext.indexOf('?') !== -1 ) {
        $('#sex-display-error').show();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0},0);
      } 
      if ( $weightdisplaytext.indexOf('?') !== -1 ) {
        $('#weight-display-error').show();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0},0);
      } 
      if ( $heighthdisplaytext.indexOf('?') !== -1 ) {
        $('#height-display-error').show();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0},0);
      } 
      if ( $hairdisplaytext.indexOf('?') !== -1 ) {
        $('#hair-display-error').show();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0},0);
      } 
      if ( $eyedisplaytext.indexOf('?') !== -1 ) {
        $('#eye-display-error').show();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0},0);
      }
```

I'm hoping someone can help explain a better way to write this code more efficiently.

Or maybe I'm over-analyzing and the way this code is written is just fine and/or isn't inefficient enough to cause any issues with performance/speed/whatever?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) You might want to check out [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) 2) You could always utilize short circuiting. `var scrollPage = checkSex || checkWeight || ...`. After one of them returns `true`, the following ones won't execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if([$sexdisplaytext,$weightdisplaytext,$heighthdisplaytext,$hairdisplaytext,$eyedisplaytext].reduce(function(status,el){
  if ( el.indexOf('?') !== -1 ) {
    el.parent.show();//TODO get the error based on its relative position in dom, like 3rd child or sth

    return true;//scroll to top
  } 
    return status;//keep old status
 },false)) $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0},0);
```

Simply loop over your elems, then scroll to top if youve found an error...

Comment: If say the user forgot 3 of the 5 "buttons", this code would only tell them they missed one right (i.e. the first one the missed)?  Then if they submit again, it would tell them the next one (rather than showing all 3 having been missing).  If so, I'm not sure that would be best user experience.  Or am I misunderstanding and this code WOULD in fact show all "required" messages, whether it's 1 or 4, at once?

Comment: @user3304303 yeah right. Edited to fit your needs...